# Trying to display photos in app only to user that posted them using firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an app that user can login to and take and add photos to a feed. im using firestore as the database.

Right now ever user can see every other users photos as well as their own. I want only the user signed in to be able view their own photos.
A user in another forum suggested that I  use firestore rules to set that control but I'm having trouble implementing to correct code.

I read through the documentation on firestore and trying to implement the code the way they have it is not working. Below is my database info and my current rules (which is not working) thank you.

Database:
[image]

```
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents { 
  
  match /{document=**}{

      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == 'byId';

      }

  }
```

I'm expecting this code to compare the uid of the user the the byId field (which should be the same) and allow them to read and write their own data if true

i also have an authentification page where uid == byId

Comment: byId is in the document, not the auth object. Try `request.auth.uid == {document}.byId`

Comment: 1) Please replace the screenshot of your rules by same rules as text, so we can copy/paste it. 2) Please show the minimal code that doesn't work as you expect it to work. --- For both of these you can the edit link under your question.

Comment: Joel- that gave me this error : Error saving rules - Line 9: Unexpected '}'.; Line 9: Unexpected '.'.

Comment: Frank-  i have made the requested updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This check `request.auth.uid == 'byId'` checks whether the UID of the current user is literally `byId`. If you want to check whether the UID is the same as ht value of the `byId` field in the document use:

```
if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.byId;
```

I also recommend checking out the Firebase documentation on [securing document access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions).

Comment: for some reason when i try that it wont let me log into the app

Comment: Accessing the database has nothing to do with signing in to Firebase Authentication, so it'll be hard to say why this happens without seeing the minimal code that reproduces that behavior and how that code meets the conditions of your security rules (i.e. what the values of the current user and the `byId` is the document are).